# How to pass data from activity to broadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android

i have code that calls a broadcast receiver, in the receiver, i try to get the extra data from the intent, but it's null.

so,

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallAlarm.class);
                          intent.putExtra("medicine", "kkk");

                          PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                  MainActivity.this,0, intent, 0);

                          AlarmManager am;
                          am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                          am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                 c.getTimeInMillis(),
                                 sender
                                );
```

and in the BroadcastReceiver.onReceiver(),

```
    String name = i.getStringExtra("medicine");
```

but medicine is null. what am i missing?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the PendingIntent with flag [`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT),

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CallAlarm.class);
 intent.putExtra("medicine", "kkk");
 PendingIntent sender=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                  MainActivity.this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This will enable you to pass the data to the BroadCastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the above code, I get value always null. My broadcast receiver starts on bootup so apart from the above code I also add intent.setAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");

Still it gives me null.